# What does pop()' do in Django Rest FrameWork?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I want to understand why this function is used for

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = ProfileSerializer()

```
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'email', 'profile')

def create(self, validated_data):
    profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
    user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
    Profile.objects.create(user=user, **profile_data)
    return user
```

Comment: You obtain the element that is associated with `'profile'`, and it is removed at the same time.

Comment: See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both **get()** and **pop()** return items, but pop() removes them from the source dict, while get() leaves them there.

However, if you try to **pop()** the same item second time, you will find that the **items has been removed from the dict** you're accessing.

- Use **pop()** when you need one time validation check & will not use
  the data further.
- And use **get()**, when you need validation check & also save
  data in database.

Answer (score 10):

validated_data is a dictionary and `.pop(key)` searches for the key specified and returns and removes it if it is found, otherwise an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

The value specified by the key will be converted to a list of OrderedDict and will be popped out. So result will have ordered values of specified key.

Answer (score 1):

`pop()` basically a python method. In the dictionary data, it takes a key as an argument and removes the matching element from the dictionary as well as returns the value of it.

Example snippet

```
elements = {'Book': 5, 'Pen' : 2, 'Pencil': 2}
removed = elements.pop('Pen')
print('Removed: ',removed)
print('Elements now: ',elements)
```

Output:

```
Removed:  2
Elements now:  {'Book': 5, 'Pencil': 2}
```

As your scenario,

```
profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
```

from `validate_data`, the element with key `profile` will be removed and its value will be stored in `profile_data` variable.